# How to hide and show material toolbar when the scrollview scrolled?

Tags: android, material-design, toolbar

In my android app I'm building a simple `ScrollView` inside a `RelativeLayout`! it also has a material `Toolbar`. How do I make the material Toolbar hide  with transition when the user scrolls up and show the Toolbar when the user scrolls down? here is the xml layout structure of my app.

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <AppBarLayout>
        <Toolbar/>
    </AppBarLayout>

    <ScrollView> 
        <!-- views -->
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Use this link: http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/android-design-support-library-codelab/en

Answer (score 2):

Make use of a NestedScrollView with a CollapsingToolbarLayout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView ...>
    <LinearLayout ...>
        ...
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

[Try this working example](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare)